# get selected row data in mantine react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mantine

I am using mantine react table in my application for showing the data on UI. In this single selection table i want to get the selected row details and want to call a function in which i need to set one state with the help of selected row details.

```
 const someFunction = () => {
    props.selectedRow({
    id: rowDetails.id,
    rowData: rowDetails,
    });
};
<MantineReactTable
                        columns={tableHeader}
                        data={tableData}
                        enableColumnActions={true}
                        enableColumnFilters={true}
                        enablePagination={true}
                        enableSorting={true}
                        enableTopToolbar={true}
                        enableRowSelection={true}
                        muiSelectCheckboxProps={{
                          color: 'secondary',
                        }}
                        enableStickyHeader
                        enableStickyFooter
                        enableSelectAll={false}
                        enableMultiRowSelection={false}
                      />
```

So i want to call someFunction everytime i select a row and want to set `props.selectedRow` value with the current selected row value. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `toggleRow()` function that will set which row is currently selected and a State object to hold it in, as well as call your function `someFunction()`. This particular implementation will also allow you to click the same row again to deselect, but you can remove that if you don't need it.

```
const [selection, setSelection] = useState('');
const toggleRow = (id: string) =>
    setSelection((current) =>
        current == id ? current = '' : current = id
    );
    someFunction()
```

Now we map this function onto the row components from our data, making `toggleRow()` the `onClick()` function.

```
const rows = events.map((item) => {
    const selected = selection.includes(item.id);
    return (
        <tr key={item.id} className={cx({ [classes.rowSelected]: selected })} onClick={() => toggleRow(item.id)}>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
        </tr>
```

Finally, we'll create a `styles` class which will highlight the row we have selected. Entirely optional, but a nice UI touch.

```
rowSelected: {
    backgroundColor:
          theme.colorScheme === 'dark'
              ? theme.fn.rgba(theme.colors[theme.primaryColor][7], 0.2)
              : theme.colors[theme.primaryColor][0],
  },
```